# Create bigrams from list of sentences in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a dataframe like this after some preprocessing. I want to create bigrams from each list in the dataframe rows. How I tried is given below. I get an error saying

```
lambda row: list((map(ngrams(2), row))))
TypeError: ngrams() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

What should be ngrams' first parameter here? How should I modify this code?

Also I may be asking questions on my every function. But I am having a hard time understanding the lamda and map functions that I am using. Please explain me how I should apply lamda and map functions on this dataframe in the future?

> Dataframe

```
 [[ive, searching, right, word, thank, breather], [i, promise, wont, take, help, granted, fulfil, promise], [you, wonderful, blessing, time]]                       

 [[free, entry, 2, wkly, comp, win, fa, cup, final, tkts, 21st, may, 2005], [text, fa, 87121, receive, entry, questionstd, txt, ratetcs, apply, 08452810075over18s]]

 [[nah, dont, think, go, usf, life, around, though]]                                                                                                                

 [[even, brother, like, speak, me], [they, treat, like, aid, patent]]                                                                                               

 [[i, date, sunday, will], []]
```

> What I need

```
 [(even, brother), (brother,like), (like,speak), (speak,me), (they, treat), (treat,like), (like,aid), (aid,patent)]
```

> What I tried

```
 def toBigram(fullCorpus):
    bigram = fullCorpus['lemmatized'].apply(
       lambda row: list((map(ngrams(2), row))))
    return bigram
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `map`, the first parameter must be a function *name*, not a function *call*. `ngrams(2)` is a function call. You cannot use `ngrams` with `map` directly. Either define a lambda function:

```
lambda row: list(map(lambda x:ngrams(x,2), row))
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
lambda row: [ngrams(x,2) for x in row]
```

Or use function `bigrams`, which is also a part of NLTK:

```
lambda row: list(map(bigrams, row))
```

Comment: Here should I access the outer list or list(list(something))? Will you please modify my function?

Comment: I added the `lambda` part.

Comment: Thanks. Why the output is '[<generator object ngrams at 0x000000F27FE39830>, <generator object ngrams at 0x000000F27FE39938>]' like this??

Comment: Thanks. I really didn't know that